# Deal with column list of multiple queries executed at runtime.

Tags: plsql

I have a list of queries stored in an Oracle DB table. My requirement is to fetch each of those queries one by one and fire them in a procedure and log their start end and elapsed times in another table

My problem is how should I handle the column list as that's going to be different for each of those queries and the number of columns and their datatypes cannot be anticipated at runtime.

Please suggest a way out.

For now, I have written down the code below. Here I have enclosed each query fetched with a count(*) to avoid the problem. However, the actual time taken for the count(*) query will be different from the time taken for the original query to execute.

Thanks a lot!

```
DECLARE
  before_time        TIMESTAMP;
  after_time         TIMESTAMP;
  elapsed_time_in_ms NUMBER;
  stmnt CLOB; --varchar(32000);
  counts   NUMBER;
  sql_no   NUMBER;
  err_mess VARCHAR2(100);
  CURSOR get_queries
  IS
    SELECT * FROM SLOW_RUNNING_SQL WHERE curr_ind = 1;

FUNCTION get_elapsed_time(
    start_time_in TIMESTAMP ,
    end_time_in   TIMESTAMP )
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  l_days         NUMBER;
  hours        NUMBER;
  minutes      NUMBER;
  seconds      NUMBER;
  milliseconds NUMBER;
BEGIN
<calculates elapsed time in milliseconds and returns that>
  RETURN milliseconds  ;
END;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
  before_time := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  FOR i IN get_queries
  LOOP
    stmnt  := i.SQL_DESC;
    sql_no := i.sql_no;
    stmnt  := 'SELECT count(*) FROM ('||stmnt||') a';
    dbms_output.put_line(stmnt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmnt INTO counts;
    after_time        := SYSTIMESTAMP;
    elapsed_time_in_ms:= get_elapsed_time(before_time,after_time);
    dbms_output.put_line(elapsed_time_in_ms);
    INSERT
    INTO query_performance_log VALUES
      (
        i.sql_no,
        stmnt,
        counts,
        before_time,
        after_time,
        elapsed_time_in_ms/1000,
        'No exception',
        elapsed_time_in_ms );
    dbms_output.put_line(stmnt);
    dbms_output.put_line(counts);
    dbms_output.put_line(after_time);
    dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(after_time - before_time));
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
  ROLLBACK;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  err_mess:= SQLERRM;
  INSERT
  INTO query_performance_log VALUES
    (
      sql_no,
      stmnt,
      0,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      0,
      err_mess,
      0
    );
  dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
  ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: One solution can be you can concatenate the columns used in your query and then get the result to a varchar field

Answer (score 0):

A solution that might suit you is to select a constant for every line returned by your query and make a `bulk collect INTO` a collection of `varchar2` variables.

Here is what you're looking for:

```
-- declare a list of varchar2:
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_my_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

-- then use this type in your proc.:
[..]
declare
  v_res   t_my_list;
[..]

-- then run the query
execute immediate 'SELECT ''x'' FROM ('||stmnt||') ' 
  bulk collect into v_res;
```

If the columns selected by your queries are "simple", the above should work fair enough to evaluate performances. But if you start calling other functions and procedures for the data you retrieve in the `select`, then its more complicate.

In this other case, then you should try to work something out to build a concatenation of the columns returned (and enlarge the `VARCHAR2(100)` in the declaration of `t_my_list`). This implies you start work on `stmnt` and extract the columns, a part being the replacement of `,` by `''||''` or so.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your help. Looks like the concatenation of the columns will be more suitable. Nevertheless more suggestions are welcome.

One doubt, will the bulk collect of all rows speed up the query as compared to select * .. ? I do not want that as i need to log the execution times of the queries.

Comment: The bulk collect makes your code retrieve every row, instead of just one row for the count. It is different for your performance testing to only retrieve the count than retrieve all rows. Maybe I didn't really understand what you intend doing.